# Load channel list from samsung smart tv

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

Is there an API (e.g. http) which gives access to the channel list of a samsung smart tv over the network?

There seems to be a device api which allows apps on the smart tv to access the channels but not over the network.

Thanks!

Comment: As i understand you want send request to the TV and get channels list ? And this without own application in smart hub?

Comment: @IlyaZ Yes.. If possible... I am also happy to create my own application if it can run in the background and makes the channel list available all the time.